# Spring testing - test endpoint with mock controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I have an existing app that I'm trying to write unit tests for... There is no real 'service' layer. It goes controller->repository->database and the endpoints are defined via annotations on the controller. I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.8 (not 1.4).

What I want to do is mock the controller to return an mock collection I can verify. What's happening INSTEAD is the app is being bootstrapped and real data is being seeded and when I call the endpoint, real app data is being returns. So, it seems I have 2 problems: I'm doing data set up and configuration I don't want performed in a unit test and, secondly, my mock controller is being ignored. They are probably related. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
 @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private ApplicationController applicationController = new ApplicationController();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {}

    @Test
    public void testEndPoints() throws Exception  {
        Application testApp = TestUtils.generateApplication();
        Mockito.when(applicationController.getApplications()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(testApp));
        log.info("Verifying applications endpoint is up and running.");

        mockMvc.perform(get("/applications/")).andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andDo(print())
               .andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].name",is("my_name")));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually in a case like this mock repository is injected into the controller, so that you can mock a method on a repository, have the collection you want, do some processing inside the controller, return modified collection. Then your unit test verifies this processed collection matches expectations.

Something like:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationRepository applicationRepository;
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private ApplicationController applicationController;

@Before
public void setup() {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();

   when(applicationRepository.findAllByIds(anyListOf(Long.class))
        .thenReturn(<the collection you want to be processed by controller>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a class for 'ServiceTests' that almost look exactly like what you have shown. Starting from scratch, I would have created a Service layer that the controller delegates to and then it has the business logic and invokes the repositories for data.    What I want to do is simply test calling the endpoints with dummy data returned and check some JSON values and http status.   If I don't mock the controller, I have issues since there are some private methods in the controller method which can't be stubbed.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you're trying to test then. I thought, you wanted to test your controller. But if you just mock it and return some data immediately, what are you testing then?